# How to make an app auto-connect to a saved vpn?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Whenever my app is running, the phone has to be connected to a specific VPN. I have to reduce user interaction as much as possible, so I want the app to auto-connect to the preconfigured VPN when the user launches it. I have zero experience, so I don't even know what to expect. The documentation online is very sparse and I couldn't put it together to retrieve useful informations. The language I'm using is C#. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [VPN service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn#add_a_service), create an Android service inheriting from VpnService. Declare the VPN service in your app manifest file with the following additions:

```
<service android:name=".MyVpnService"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_VPN_SERVICE">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.net.VpnService"/>
     </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Set VPN [always-on](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn#always-on) to keep VPN service running while the device is on. And don't forget to add permissions.